# Angular 4/5/6 Global Variables

Tags: angular, typescript

I really struggle with creating global variables in my Angular 2 application.

So I have my file called **globals.ts**, which looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";


@Injectable()
export class Globals {

  var role = 'test';

}
```

And I want to use the variable role in my HTML view of my component like this:

```
{{ role }}
```

I already added the globals.ts file to my **app.module.ts** in the following way:

```
providers: [
  Globals
],
```

No matter what I did on this file, it just didn't work. What I don't want to do is to have to import the globals.ts file in every component manually, which is why I want to use the providers feature.

Comment: `export class Globals {

  var role = 'test';

}` <- what's that?

Comment: That is supposed to be my class Globals in which i want to store my global variables. For example the variable "role", which right now should have a string "test" in it, just to test if the global variables work.

Comment: It's not valid typescript though.

Comment: Should I remove the "var"?

Comment: what about using `localStorage`?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You can access `Globals` entity from any point of your App via [Angular dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#angular-dependency-injection). If you want to output `Globals.role` value in some component's template, you should inject `Globals` through the component's constructor like any service:

```
// hello.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Globals } from './globals';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: 'The global role is {{globals.role}}',
  providers: [ Globals ] // this depends on situation, see below
})

export class HelloComponent {
  constructor(public globals: Globals) {}
}
```

I provided `Globals` in the `HelloComponent`, but instead it could be provided in some `HelloComponent's` parent component or even in `AppModule`. It will not matter until your `Globals` has only static data that could not be changed (say, constants only). But if it's not true and for example different components/services might want to change that data, then the `Globals` must be a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). In that case it should be provided in the topmost level of the hierarchy where it is going to be used. Let's say this is `AppModule`:

```
import { Globals } from './globals'

@NgModule({
  // ... imports, declarations etc
  providers: [
    // ... other global providers
    Globals // so do not provide it into another components/services if you want it to be a singleton
  ]
})
```

Also, it's impossible to use *var* the way you did, it should be

```
// globals.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  role: string = 'test';
}
```

**Update**

At last, I created a simple [demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x32any), where single `Globals` is being shared between 3 components and one of them can change the value of `Globals.role`.

Comment: @AtulStha I just shifted demo from Plunker to Stackblitz, thanks for the issue.

Comment: so the global variable looses its new data when the page reloads, isnt there a way to keep that saved somewhere for a specific session

Comment: @AtulStha Persisting the data between the App sessions is another story. Here we have cookie, local/session storages, url params, at least a remote database with save/read API... SO has many good questions/answers on this topic, if they do not match your needs, open another one.

Comment: I understand your answer as **technically** one may put the global constants (*glonstants* as we call them) both in a separate file or in the root module (usually called *app*). One thing that experience taught me is that developers should minimize the number of decisions they make to keep structure predictable and standardized. What you said, clearly opens for two different approaches and I wonder if there's a preferred way or, to avoid opinion base, if it's possible to motivate when to use which.

Comment: This is fine but why call it `Globals` when they're not global in the usual sense?

Comment: I am not able to change the value of string by using the method as shown in the demo! Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @GauravSachdeva You may post your issue as a separate question on SO, I believe it would be the best option. Add link to it in comments if you want me to see on it.

Comment: Actually, as I am new to Angular 6 so I wasn't aware of the fact that service loads after every refresh. As i want my data to persist in-between the redirect and refresh, so I guess this is not correct way to do that. Thanks!

Comment: can you please explain, why your example is better than just to define all constants in  GlobalConst.js like  e.g. 
export const customError   = ['Please try again'];
export const myUrl    = '/example'; 

and using them in other components by just importing them:
import * from './GlobalConst';

Comment: @dgraf that should also work and I would prefer this one over the one with a service. However, correctly implemented you could reassign values in the service if needed (e.g. new state) but exported const cannot be reassigned.

Comment: it works fine @dhilt, but only in development mode, actually, we can't access private members in HTML, (private globals: Globals) by making the "globals" private variable it can't be accessible in the HTML, and we don't want it to make public. In production mode, it gives the error while making the build. so what should we do in that case

Comment: @RazaEllahi Just replace `private` with `public` in the constructor's argument definition. I agree with you, it is important catch, so I'm going to update the answer and the demo.

Answer (score 31):

I use environment for that. It works automatically and you don't have to create new injectable service and most usefull for me, don't need to import via constructor.

1) Create environment variable in your **environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    ...
    // runtime variables
    isContentLoading: false,
    isDeployNeeded: false
}
```

2) **Import environment.ts** in *.ts file **and create** public **variable** (i.e. "env") to be able to use in html template

```
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';

@Component(...)
export class TestComponent {
    ...
    env = environment;
}
```

3) Use it in template...

```
<app-spinner *ngIf='env.isContentLoading'></app-spinner>
```

in *.ts ...

```
env.isContentLoading = false
```

(or just environment.isContentLoading in case you don't need it for template)

---

You can create your own set of globals within environment.ts like so:

```
export const globals = {
    isContentLoading: false,
    isDeployNeeded: false
}
```

and import directly these variables (y)

Comment: What about when you make production build? Do you have everything in two places?

Comment: This is best way. @Mulperi Not necessary to create globals in environment.ts. Just create a globals.ts in app directory with above exports and import this file where you want to use those globals.

Comment: I agree. I recently modified this solution exactly like @PrasadW pointed out.

Comment: New Angular versions do use exactly that approach by default now. There is a `environments/environment.ts` and `environments/environment.prod.ts` that are replaced automatically.

Comment: who invented Angular should have had this simplicity in mind!

Answer (score 0):

While all the other answers previously mentioned are correct. The Angular way would be is using either Pipes, Decorators or Components

If you simply want to display a string then use a component

**Component**

```html
<Role></Role>
```

**Decorator**

If you want to do something like this:

```html
<a href="/foo/{{userId}}/bar">Link</a>
```

You may want to implement your own decorator

```html
<a [customHref]="[/foo/:userId/bar]">Link</a>
```

or if you use the built in router module with routerlink you could simply extend the RouterLink directive and implement your changes.

**Pipe**

```
somevariable = "this is my #:userId";
```

```html
{{someVariable | applyglobals}}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

I use environment variables in combination with other json files, i.e. to display build information and other stuff. That way, you can mix and/or re-use them in different environments.

```
// environment.ts, environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  
  ...
  appName: require('../../package.json').name,
  appVersion: require('../../package.json').version,

  ...
  globalX: require('../../globals.json').X,
  globalY: require('../../globals.json').Y,      
}
```

Usage:

```
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  appName = environment.appName;
  buildVersion = environment.appVersion;
  x = environment.globalX;
  y = environment.globalY;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really recommended but none of the other answers are really global variables. For a truly global variable you could do this.

### Index.html

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script>
    myTest = 1;
  </script>
</body>
```

### Component or anything else in Angular

..near the top right after imports:

```
declare const myTest: any;
```

...later:

```
console.warn(myTest); // outputs '1'
```

Comment: It's the same as using the window object.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Window object and access it everwhere.
example window.defaultTitle = "my title";
then you can access window.defaultTitle without importing anything.

Comment: This is what it want to avoid.