# Angular 4: global variable is undefined

Tags: angular

I use **Angular ^4.2.4**.

Need global function **range** for all components:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Global {

  range:object = function(n:number){

    var vs = [];

    for( var i=0; i < n; i++ )
      vs.push(i);

    return vs;
  }
}
```

Component example of root:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Global } from "./global";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root'
  ,templateUrl: '<ul><li *ngFor="let i of global.range(5)">{{i}}</li></ul>'
  ,providers: [ Global ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor( public global: Global ){}
}
```

But console log is:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppHome.ngfactory.js:19)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13065)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12245)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12610)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12542)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12251)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12610)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12568)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12246)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12610)
```

That [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991306/angular-4-global-variables) don't work for me...

Comment: why you are having a function in place of a variable?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ihdogKe9PBs8bce06cZZ?p=preview it is working in this plunker..

Answer (score 1):

1) Make your method `public`

```
@Injectable()
export class Global {

   public range(n:number): number[] {
     const vs: number[] = [];

     for( let i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        vs.push(i);
     }

     return vs;
   }

}
```

2) Change `templateUrl` to `template`

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   template: '<ul><li *ngFor="let i of global.range(5)">{{ i }}</li></ul>',
   providers: [Global]
})
export class AppComponent {
   constructor( public global: Global ) { }
}
```

Comment: forget about "template", before it was path to file
but still have same error

Comment: Try to change the `Global` name

Answer (score 0):

You should use modifiers like:

```
public;
private;
protected;
```

when You declaring variables like: `public range`;