# Angular 4 extend base component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Base Component extended by its children, but when we create a new Component in Angular using angular-cli it creates html and css files, but I will not use these files from base component.

Is there a way to create a Base Component without html and css?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  templateUrl: './base.component.html', //I dont need this
  styleUrls: ['./base.component.css'] ////I dont need this
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}


import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { BaseComponent } from '../base/base.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Omit `@Component` annotation in the base component. But I suspect you might be doing something wrong in general. Why do you want to have a base component in the first place?

Comment: Cause I want to share some variables and methods which are in common in all the child components.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I removed @Component and remove it from module declarations.

Comment: I would recommend a global service that you import into each component, much cleaner

Comment: @Szenmu call you provide an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991306/angular-4-5-global-variables/43991457
That would be a great example of what I mean there

Comment: I suggest using a base component class only if all of the sub classes are going to use all of the methods and fields that defined in base class. Otherwise you will end up with a lot of dead code when it's compiled to JS.

Comment: @s.alem Can you please explain what you mean by dead code? I believe there is a reason why we've inheritance. I don't understand why nowadays Angular and React library authors don't care about that much!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since base class doesn't need to be instantiated on its own, it's abstract class and doesn't need to have `@Component` decorator.

If it has dependencies, and there's a chance that `constructor` will be omitted in child classes and inherited, base class should have `@Injectable` decorator:

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public dep: Dep) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent {
  // dummy constructor can be omitted
/*
  constructor(dep: Dep) {
    super(dep);
  }
*/
}
```

Comment: When I use "@Injectable()" my child component doesn't need to do "super()" call?

Comment: Yes. And you don't need `@Injectable()` if base class doesn't have dependencies.

Comment: @EstusFlask that's a nice trick with `@Injectable()`. Why does it work? Is it documented somewhere officially?

Comment: @bersling Yes, https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable . See also the explanation on how it works, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39029435/3731501

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask , but is it okay if we don't put any decorator and just make it an abstract class? Neither `@Component` nor `@Injectable`? It works fine but I'm just thinking about what could go wrong?

Comment: @RachitMagon IIRC this depended on Angular version and AOT/JIT compiler. I'm positive omitted `@Injectable` caused problems at some point. The provided way (a decorator on both parent and child) is a way it's guaranteed to work. For the record, did you use latest version and AOT?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm using Angular 8 & JIT