# Typescript Global variable: Counter

Tags: typescript, angular5

The template cannot and does not use a *ngFor. I need an implementation to increment and display a counter when each occurrence of `incrementQuestionNumber()` is encountered. The Globals class is injected in my component however a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` exception is thrown.

**Template:**

```
<div>
{{ globals.incrementQuestionNumber() }}. What is your favorite color?
</div>
<div>
{{ globals.incrementQuestionNumber() }}. What is your favorite car?
</div>
<div>
{{ globals.incrementQuestionNumber() }}. Who is your favorite person?
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
    static question_number: number = 1;

    incrementQuestionNumber() {
        return ++Globals.question_number;
    }
}
```

**Update:**
In case the final implementation isn't obvious (to others), it is provided below however another issue was introduced:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { Globals } from './globals';

@Directive({
  selector: '[counter]'
})
export class CounterDirective {

  constructor(private globals: Globals, private  el: ElementRef) {
  let counter = globals.incrementQuestionNumber();
  let html = el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
  let match = html.match(/^(\d+)/)
  if (match === null)
      el.nativeElement.innerHTML = counter + '. ' + html; // Doesn't execution when tab is navigated to...
  }

}
```

Comment: Refer to original post at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991306/angular-4-5-global-variables/43991457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Globals` misuses static property. Since the service is expected to be a singleton (it is a singleton when it's provided in a module), it should be:

```
@Injectable()
export class Globals {
    question_number: number = 1;

    incrementQuestionNumber() {
        return ++this.question_number;
    }
}
```

`{{ globals.incrementQuestionNumber() }}` will naturally result in `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, because it's incremented not just on each occurrence but on each expression evaluation, it's unstable.

To be incremented once per occurrence in a template, it should be a directive or component:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[question]' })
class QuestionDirective {
  constructor(public globals: Globals) {
    globals.incrementQuestionNumber();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // decrement question number?
  }
}
```

Which is used like:

```
<div question>What is your favorite color?</div>
```

Since 'question' entity is likely supposed to provide something more than just a string, `QuestionDirective` may be responsible for other question-related things and become a component.

Comment: An interesting issue was introduced when implementing your recommendation. As I navigate between ng-bootstrap tabs, the counter directive is executed and the question numbers increment when they already have been incremented once. Is there to instruct a directive to execute once or is there a configuration option that addresses this issue. See [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples)

Comment: It seems that I may need to adjust Angular 5 change detection? But I am unsure if the tab component or the directive should be changed if that is what should be done.

Comment: This is what `decrement question number` is for. You can decrement it when a directive is destroyed, so it won't be counted twice. No, this has nothing to do with change detection. Directive and component instances don't last forever, you can't rely on that. I'm not sure what's the purpose of that. Are you trying to count all 'questions' that are used in your app? Doing this in templates would be wrong approach for that.

Comment: I guess I assumed once a template or component is rendered that I could rely on it remaining rendered. Perhaps Angular does this to ensure resources are consumed minimally. However, this approach departs from how server-side templates behave. Or I should say that server-side templates do not behave this way. With that said, on the server I can reply on this expected behavior. As a result each question will be counted on the server instead...unless you have a different "client-side approach".

Comment: I guess your conclusions are correct. The comparison with server or client template engines (e.g. Handlebars) isn't correct because Angular isn't just template engine and doesn't stop working after initial rendering. If you're translating this piece of code from server side template to Angular then your approach should differ drastically in order to end up with Angular app that makes sense.