# Angular 2+ - Make global variable automatically update when value changed

Tags: angular, typescript

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43991457/7405706

Global Variable is automatically updated its value when using `{{globals.role}}`

but not when I defined `role = this.globals.role;` and display using `{{role}}`

The only way I found to make `role` variable update is creating a method to update it manually.

```
updateRole(){
    this.role = this.globals.role;
}
```

I want to know is there any way to implement this to make it update automatically. Thanks

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nj8kue) (Also modified from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43991457/3211932))** (I modified only `component1.ts` file)

Comment: Ah now, I could see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Primitive data types are passed by value**

A possible solution could be using getter like:

```
get role() {
  return this.globals.role;
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtlgan?file=src/app/component1.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to trigger the update automatically.
If you really want to use it, then you can have component1 inside component2 and pass the role as `@Input`, so that it can be updated automatically.
Or just use the global alone instead of role.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the service property instead of using the component role property

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

import {Globals} from './globals'

@Component({
  selector: 'component2',
  template: `
    <div>
      Component 2
      <br />
      <br />
      <input [(ngModel)]="globals.role" />
      {{varP}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class Component2 {

  constructor(public  globals: Globals) {
  }

}
```