# How to insert global config into index.html in Angular's ng serve?

Tags: angular

I am building an application which has to work as SaaS and each of clients could have an individual instance or set of app instances. Backend is built on to top Go lang and frontend is Angular 6 atm.
To make a service to be configurable I have to define a globally recognized configuration which will be injected into `index.html`.
I am familiar with environments concept but it doesn't fit my requirements because I have to let customers be able to change parameters. For example google analytics id.

In current Angular design it is possible to recompile app for each clients or use a service to retrieve parameters from the server which decreases startup time due to one extra roundtrip.

To overcome this I plan to inject something like

```
<script>
window.myAppGlobalConfig = { param1: 'value1' };
</script>
```

It does work perfectly with AgularJS (I used to do it before) but it seems a little bit more confusing and unclear for Angular 6.

Technically I can define an interface and use it but I want to be able use this stuff with `ng serve` but I couldn't figure out how to configure it.

My question is: **how to inject the custom js config *inline* into the index.html file?**

Comment: Why not try to more angular approach like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991306/angular-4-5-6-global-variables/43991457#43991457

Comment: Because Angular approach requires rebuilding the app or having a configuration loader.

Answer (score 1):

> Step - 1 : **Create** a js file

Just add a js file inside the assets directory

Let say the name is **config.js** and put all configurations inside that
Eg :

```
var myAppGlobalConfig = { param1: 'value1' };
var BASE_URL = "http://xxx.backend.xxx/api/";
var GET_DATA = BASE_URL + "data.go";
```

> Step - 2 : **Include** in index.html

Now in the index.html just include that script before any other script

```
<script src="assets/config.js"></script>
```

> Step - 3: Use them inside your **typescript** classes

For example, you can assign http endpoint addresses.

```
this.http.get(window["DATA_URL"]).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what I am not getting in your question?
Check my new edit :) @zoonman

Comment: I need to have script to be inline within index.html

Answer (score -1):

You can place any external `js` files on `src/assets/external.js`

Make sure that `assets` is included in `.angular-cli.json`

In your `index.html`, add `<script src="assets/external.js"></script>`

On build, you should be able to see it in `build/assets`

To use it, you can `declare var myGlobalVar: any`

Comment: I need to have script to be inline within index.html

Comment: @zoonman how about creating a shortcut file inline with index.html that just open whats inside the asset.