# declare variable in angular in a way that all functions have access to it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

im creating the window variable over and over again how can i declare it only once ?
i tried adding it to the constructor but that didn't work.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ae-test';

  constructor(
    private _ES: ElectronService, 
    ) {}

  minWindow() {
    const window = this._ES.remote.getCurrentWindow(); 
    window.minimize();
  }
  fullscreenWindow() {
    const window = this._ES.remote.getCurrentWindow()
    if (window.isFullScreen() == true) {
      window.setFullScreen(false);
    } else {
      window.setFullScreen(true);
    }
  }
  closeWindow() {
    const window = this._ES.remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.minimize();
  }

}
```

Comment: just bind it to a class property and initialize it in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a shared singleton service

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {

  private _data = {value:0};

  getData(){
    return this._data; // get ref of the data object 
  }
}
```

> notice that every time you ask for data you got the same object so
>   there is need to create a property in the component body unless you
>   want to display the object in the template

shared or singleton service is just a **service** add to *AppModule*  or *root* module providers list

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [GlobalService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

if you want to render any data from the data object you need to create a property in the component body a,b to hold a reference of the object.

```
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

  data;
  constructor(public _g:GlobalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this._g.getData()
  }

}
```

in case you just want to change the data c component

```
export class CComponent  {

 data;
  constructor(public _g:GlobalService) { }

  reset() {
    const data = this._g.getData(); // 
    data.value = 0;
  }

  inc(){
    const data = this._g.getData(); // 
    data.value +=10; 
  }

}
```

> in the global service `getData` return a **reference** to _data object ***not a new object every time***

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmlsqo)

Answer (score 1):

Define a new property in your component and assign it once in your constructor (or even better `ngOnInit` if you implement the `OnInit` lifecycle hook):

```
private window: any;

constructor(private _ES: ElectronService) {
  this.window = this._ES.remote.getCurrentWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add `window` variable to component nad set it in the `ngOnInit` hook:

```
this.window = this._ES.remote.getCurrentWindow();
```

Answer (score 1):

just use a global variable

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ae-test';
  window = null;
  constructor(
    private _ES: ElectronService, 
    ) {
  this.window = this._ES.remote.getCurrentWindow(); 
}

  minWindow() {
    this.window.minimize();
  }
  fullscreenWindow() {
    if (this.window.isFullScreen() == true) {
      this.window.setFullScreen(false);
    } else {
      this.window.setFullScreen(true);
    }
  }
  closeWindow() {
    this.window.minimize();
  }

   }
```

you can initialise window in the ngOnInit function too

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by this answer. So it's a possible repeated question:

[Angular Globals variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991306/angular-4-5-6-global-variables/43991457)