# Reload Angular 6 component after login

Tags: angular

I have a menu, which should be updated after the user has logged in. The menu is added in the app.component's html.

The menu is generated with the use of the following code.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of menuitems">
     <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[item.url]" routerLinkActive="active" {{item.name}}</a>
</li>
```

The menu items is changed after the user is logged in. I would like to force the page to reload (ideally just that component) when the user is logged in. When I do a manual refresh I get the new menu.

The component is added to the main component. With the use of

```
<app-menu></app-menu>
```

The menuitems are defined like this;

```
async ngOnInit() {
     this.menuitems = await this.menus.getMenu();
}
```

The menu service returns the elements if the user is logged in or not.

I guess that I have to update the menu component after the login has been successful, but I do not know how this can be done.

Comment: Where do you put your `login page/component`?

Comment: How are you logging the user in? You just need to update the menu in that function.

Comment: I am using a login component, which if the user is accepted the token is stored in local storage. I get that I have to update it, I was wondering how this can be done. Is there  function I need to call?

Answer (score 0):

this may be the simplest way just use *`ngIf` to show or hide the element ,every time you toggle the state the component will recreated and `ngOninit` will run again

example case

*template*

```
<div>
  <button (click)="login()">login ‍♂️</button>
</div>
```

*component*

```
toggle = true;

  constructor(private m:MenuService) {

  }

  login(){
    console.log('logging');
    this.toggle = false;

    this.m.menus = ['admin','log out']; // update menus result
    setTimeout(() => this.toggle = true,1500); // api call 
  }
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-toggle-state)

Comment: How do I force that component to be toggled after I log in?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen I have add a demo that simulate your case 

Comment: is that the "normal" way switching between two menus?

Comment: I don't got what you said   ??

Comment: I was wondering if that is the normal way of displaying one  of N amount of different menus. If the user is logged in, there will be a  menu based on that user's level, with this solution, I could make it work, by just toggling the different menus, but I was wondering if this is the normal way of doing such an operation.

Comment: possible in that case you can use ngSwitch  there is no wrong with that

Comment: In my example there are several components: the menu resides inside app.ts, the menu is generated in menu.ts and it should be updated from login.ts, how can login change the variable for app.ts, which then again triggers the ngif

Comment: just a global service @AtleKristiansen

Comment: How do I create a global service?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen shared service is servie create once and you will got the same instant every time you inject that service ,I have answered about this topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631903/declare-variable-in-angular-in-a-way-that-all-functions-have-access-to-it/55635586#55635586 check the demo

Answer (score -1):

If component has any input parameter being passed from parent component which changes on successful login then you can implement OnChanges interface need to define ngOnChanges event, which would get executed on input parameter change.

```
async ngOnChanges() {
this.menuitems = await this.menus.getMenu();
}
```

Comment: This would update the menu way too many times and lead to performance issues if this pattern was repeated throughout the application.