# Problem to use gettext to parse .po translation file

Tags: angular, typescript, gettext

I try to use ngx-translate with the .po loader; but during compile time I receive the following warning:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js 9:12-34
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

This warning is related to the following line of code:

```
const po = gettext.po.parse(contents, 'utf-8');
```

At runtime I see the following error & the application does not work:

```
index.js:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.js (index.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/encoding/lib/encoding.js (encoding.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/gettext-parser/lib/poparser.js (poparser.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/gettext-parser/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

I searched the net and stack overflow, but could not find the solution to this issue.

Is there an alternative to gettext to parse .po files; or what is the solution to get this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4/5/6 Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991306/angular-4-5-6-global-variables)

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it fast this by adding these code in index.html

```
 <script>
    var global = global || window;
    var Buffer = Buffer || [];
    var process = process || {
       env: { DEBUG: undefined },
       version: []
    };
  </script>
```

**BETTER FIX**

Step 1: Add script to package.json

```
"postinstall": "node patch-iconv.js && node patch-ng-devkit.js"
```

Step 2: Create a file same directory with package.json and named "**patch-iconv.js**" content:

```js
// IIFE
(function() {

  'use strict';

  // node
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');

  // Patch encoding module due to iconv issues -> make it use iconv-lite
  (function() {
    var PATCH_VERSION = '0.1.12';
    var PATCH_MODULE = 'encoding';
    var PATCH_REASON = 'Use iconv-lite instead of iconv, helpful for webpack bundling';
    console.log('patching `%s`(%s) module', PATCH_MODULE, PATCH_VERSION);
    var pathToModule = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', PATCH_MODULE);
    var pathToModulePackage = path.join(pathToModule, 'package.json');
    var pathToModulePatchedFile1 = path.join(pathToModule, 'lib/iconv-loader.js');
    var pathToModulePatchedFile2 = path.join(pathToModule, 'lib/encoding.js');
    var moduleInfo = require(pathToModulePackage);
    if (moduleInfo.version !== PATCH_VERSION) {
      console.error(
        'patching `encoding` failed - expected `%s` but detected `%s`',
        PATCH_VERSION,
        moduleInfo.version
      );
      process.exit(1);
    }
    var contents;
    if (fs.existsSync(pathToModulePatchedFile1)) {
      contents = [
        '\'use strict\';',
        'module.exports = require(\'iconv-lite\');',
        '',
      ].join('\n');
      fs.writeFileSync(pathToModulePatchedFile1, contents);
    } else {
      console.error('patching `%s` failed because the file does not exist in', PATCH_MODULE, pathToModule);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    if (fs.existsSync(pathToModulePatchedFile2)) {
      contents = fs.readFileSync(pathToModulePatchedFile2).toString();
      contents = contents.replace('console.error(E);','');
      fs.writeFileSync(pathToModulePatchedFile2, contents);
    } else {
      console.error('patching `%s` failed because the file does not exist in', PATCH_MODULE, pathToModule);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log('patching `%s`, reason: `%s` - completed', PATCH_MODULE, PATCH_REASON);
  })();


  })(this);
```

Step 3: Create a file same directory with package.json and named "**patch-ng-devkit.js**" content:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const f = 'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js';

fs.readFile(f, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(/node: false/g, 'node: {crypto: true, stream: true}');

  fs.writeFile(f, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Step 4:  then run

```
npm run postinstall
```

DONE, 
Build again and worked